# How to do drill down from table component to another dashboard in pentaho?

Tags: javascript, pentaho-cde

I am trying to navigate from table component of one dashboard to another dashboard which is also having table component in pentaho CDE.I set dashboard-1 table component 1st column as hyperlink which is going to be clicked and i put some js on ClickAction menu..

### JS on ClickAction

function testClick(e) {
var id = e.tableData[e.rowIdx][0];
window.location ='http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/%3Apublic%3ASU-KAM%3APR_Item.wcdf/generatedContent'+'?item_desc=' +id;
}

I am passing URL of Dashboard-2 and the parameter needs to be reflect on dashboard-2.

On Dashboard-2 i have created custom_parameter to receive parameter value from dashboard-1 which is
---> item_category=Dashboards.getQueryParameter("item_category") .

I set the parameters and listeners correctly on dashboard-2 and passed the parameter name in my chart component query.

But i didn't get any reflection on dashboard-2 when i click on dashboard-1.It's navigating to dashboard-2 but it showing empty data.

Help me guys.

THANKS,
Kannas

Comment: Did you set your parameter on Dashboard 2 to be bookmarkable? If it's bookmarkable its value can be passed in the URL, but if it's not, then there's no way to override the dashboard's default.

Comment: Thank you nsousa.. Its working fine now.. you saved me..